# get size of compressed file while compressing

Tags: python, gzip, zlib

I currently try to create a module that writes a *.gz file up to a specific size. I want to use it for a custom log handler to specify the maximum size of a zipped logfile. I already made my way through the [gzip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) and also the [zlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html).

I could use zlib right away and measure the length of my compressed bytearray, but then I would have to create and write the gzip file header by myself. The zlib-documentaion itself says: `For reading and writing .gz files see the gzip module.`.
But I do not see any option for getting the size of the compressed file in the gzip module.

the `logfile` opened via `logfile = gzip.open("test.gz", "ab", compresslevel=6)` does have a `.size` parameter, but this is the size of the original file, not the compressed file.

Also `os.path.getsize("test.gz")` is zero until `logfile` is closed and is actually written to the disk.

Do you have any idea how I can use the built-in gzip module to close a compressed file once it reached a certain size? Without closing and re-opening it all the time?

Or is this even possible?
Thanks for any help on this!

**Update**:
It is not true that no data is written to disk until the file is closed, it just takes some time to collect some kilobytes before the filesize changes. This is good enogh for me and my usecase, so this is solved. Thanks for any input!

My test code for this:

```
import os
import gzip
import time

data = 'Hello world'
limit = 10000
i = 0

logfile = gzip.open("test.gz", "wb", compresslevel=6)
while i < limit:
    msg = f"{data} {str(i)} \n"
    logfile.write(msg.encode("utf-8"))
    print(os.path.getsize("test.gz"))
    print(logfile.size)
    if i > 1000:
        logfile.flush()
        break
    #time.sleep(0.03)
    i += 1
logfile.close()
print(f"final size of *.gz file: {os.path.getsize('test.gz')}")
print(f"final size of logfile object file: {logfile.size}")
```

Answer (score 0):

gzip does not actually compress the file until after you close it so it does no really make sense to ask to know the size of the compressed file beforehand. One thing you could do is look at the size of compressed files you obtain on real data from your use case and do a linear regression to have some kind of approximation of the compression ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just updated the start post, gzip does write the data to the disk before closing the file, but it needs to be enough data. But then you can simply watch the file via `os.path.getsize()` or if you use gzip with a file-object you can watch the file objects `.tell()` function